# How to Update data in 4th tab fragment from main activity android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**I have 4 tab in mainactivity with viewpagerAdpater. From 4th fragment I am going to another activity and from there I am passing data throguh bundle into main activity . Now senario is taht I wanted to send that data Into 4th tab fragment.
I aprecaite if anyone explain me out with correct solution.**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
  Tab3--- I wanted to send data directly mainacitivty to 3 fragment .

public class TabFragment3 extends Fragment {

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_3, container, false);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Find 4th fragment by id or tag u have given and then use the same to pass data.

Comment: could you send me some pseudo code . because i tried to do with it its crashing.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @Ritesh could you please answer . i would appreciate . but read description. I wanted to send data directly to 3 rd fragment

Comment: post your pager adapter as well.

Comment: Sorry  I am not able to post it . but same example I am following.http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/